# How to fix this Makefile

Tags: makefile

Instead of executable code all it does is create files that don't do anything, even if the files are made executable.

```
TARGETS = load list show add delete btree
all: $(TARGETS)
%: %.cpp
    g++ $< -g -o $@ -MM -MF $@.dd
    sed "s/$@\.o:/$@:/" $@.dd > $@.d
    -@rm $@.dd

DEPS=$(TARGETS:%=%.d)
-include $(DEPS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running g++ with the `-MM` option, to create the dependency file. But this option causes g++ to write a dependency file *instead* of a binary.

Try this:

```
TARGETS = load list show add delete btree
all: $(TARGETS)
%: %.cpp
    g++ $< -g -o $@
    g++ $< -g -MM -MF $@.dd
    sed "s/$@\.o:/$@:/" $@.dd > $@.d
    -@rm $@.dd

DEPS=$(TARGETS:%=%.d)
-include $(DEPS)
```